# How can I efficiently move many files to a new server?

Tags: linux, zip, gzip, tar

I'm switching hosting providers and need to transfer millions of uploaded files to a new server.  All of the files are in the same directory.  Yes.  You read that correctly.  ;)

In the past I've done this:

1. Zip all of the files from the source server
2. `scp` the zip to the new server
3. Unzip
4. Move directory to appropriate location

   - for whatever reason my zips from step 1 always bring the path along with them and require me to mv.

The last time I did this it took about 4-5 days to complete and that was about 60% of what I have now.

I'm hoping for a better way.  What do you suggest?

File structure is hashed.  Something like this: `AAAAAAAAAA.jpg` - `ZZZZZZZZZZ.txt`

Here's one idea we're tossing around:

Split the zips into tons of mini-zips based on 3 letter prefixes.  Something like:

```
AAAAAAAAAA.jpg - AAAZZZZZZZ.gif => AAA.zip
```

Theoretical Pros:

- could speed up transfer, allowing multiple zips to transfer at once
- could limit time lost to failed transfer.  (waiting 2 days for a transfer to ultimately fail is awful)

Theoretical Cons:

- could slow down the initial zip considerably since the zip has to look up the files through a wildcard (`AAA*`), perhaps offset by running many zip threads at once, using all CPUs instead of only one.
- Complexity?

We've also thought about rsync and scp but worry about the expense of transferring each file manually.  And since the remote server is empty I don't need to worry about what's already there.

What do you think?  How would you do it?

(Yes, I'll be moving these to Amazon S3 eventually, and I'll just ship them a disk, but in the meantime, I need them up yesterday!)

Comment: In this sort of situation my primary concern would be to not repeat the transfer than transfer fast. I once had to transfer 100GB worth files from locations 7 seas apart. I tried with large file and upload failed due to some random error and had to do entire thing again. So what I did was divided files into 6gb chunks and send them parallely (3-4) at a time. It was lot faster and more reliable. You can just create a script to do that automatically for you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You actually have multiple options, my favorite would be using `rsync`.

```
rsync [dir1] [dir2]
```

This command will actually compare the directories, and sync only the differences between them.

With this, I would be most likeley to use the following

```
rsync -z -e ssh user@example.com:/var/www/ /var/www/
```

> -z Zip
>   -e Shell Command

You could also use SFTP, FTP via SSH.

Or even `wget`.

```
wget -rc ssh://user@example.com:/var/www/
```

Comment: Wouldn't rsync require effort to compare each file?  The remote directory is empty, so why add that expense?  Also, is transferring millions of files more efficient than one (or even a 1000) compressed files?

Comment: I am not sure about the comparison. And you originally suggested compression, so i just threw it in here as an option to you. Why not just a standard FTP connection..? Or even wget -rc ssh://user@example.com:/var/www/

Comment: Rsync's comparison is based on the hash of diskblocks (for existing files) For non-existing files there is nothing to compare (except for *maybe* a final verification after the copy)

Comment: `rsync` is absolutely the correct thing to use, not only is it hassle-free, but it also does not upload identical files (or identical segments of different files) twice. The 2-step algorithm it uses (fast rolling checksum followed by strong checksum) is sufficiently efficient, too. Among millions of uploaded files, there is a good chance that some of the files will be identical (e.g. the same pirated software, song, or movie uploaded by different users, or identical snippets of text or source code).

Comment: How did the file transfer go? If this helped you, it would be helpful to mark it as an accepted answer so that it will be easier for others to find and use as well!

Comment: Under the hood, rsync does not use any parallelism. It downloads one file, compares to local version, and uploads if necessary. Then it proceeds with next file, and the next, and the next. ZERO parallelism. ZERO performance advantage during first copy.

Answer (score 1):

I'm from the Linux/Unix world.  I'd use **tar** to make a number of tar files each of a set size.  E.g.:

```
tar -cML $MAXIMUM_FILE_SIZE_IN_KILOBYTES --file=${FILENAME}}_{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}.tar  ${THE_FILES}
```

I'd skip recompression unless your .txt files are huge.  You won't get much mileage of out recompressing .jpeg files, and it will eat up a lot of CPU (and real) time.

I'd look into how your traffic shaping works.  How many concurrent connections can you have?  How much bandwidth per connection?  How much total?

I've seen some interesting things with **scp**.  Testing out a home network, **scp** gave much lower throughput than copying over a mounted shared smbfs filesystem.  I'm not entirely clear why.  Though that may be desirable if **scp** is verifying the copy and requesting retransmission on errors.  (There is a very small probability of an error making it through in a packet transmitted over the internet.  Without some sort of subsequent verification stage that's a real problem with large data sets.  You might want to run md5 hashes...)

If this is a webserver, you could always just use wget.  Though that seems highly inefficient...

Comment: Agreed about compression.  Most of our files are images and don't compress. However the concern is about the expense of transferring many files (10M+) instead of just one (or 1000).  Do you think scp could handle that better than compressing on the front end?  How should I gauge the I/O expense and connection expense?

Answer (score 0):

What about using BitTorrent? It may not be as easy to setup, but once you have it going it should do exactly what you want. BitTorrent was developed to facilitate the transferring of larges files. You would need a client on the source machine and one on the destination machine. Create the metafile on the source machine. Copy it to the destination machine and load it up in your BitTorrent client. Manually enter in the IP to the source machine. As long as you have no firewalls blocking you, the transfer should start. Optionally you could zip up all the files first using no compression aka STORED compression and then transfer the zip using BitTorrent.